# Thunderbird can't authenticate to sync my Gmail account

Tags: thunderbird, gmail

I installed Thunderbird and had no problem. When I try to sync my Gmail account it displays an error message about having the wrong username and password.

I already made the necessary changes in Gmail; I followed all the steps from Gmail and Thunderbird tutorials. How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have two step verification?

Comment: Don't, just one. I insert my name, email and password, then click on OK button. The Thunderbird tells me that it couldn't connect and give more fields to fill when I click on "manually configuration" or something like this. The other button is "try again". When I try manually I try some combinations of security type (I can choose from a list) because I don't know and I've never found nothing about it.

Answer (score 0):

You might be bumping into the latest Thunderbird bug with using the OAuth Authentication method.  Do you get a popup in a google https window that asks for your username and then will not let you click on "next"?

If so add the account to Thunderbird by allowing it to auto detect the server settings.  Then select "manual" and change the Authentication types from "OAuth2" to "Normal Password" for both incoming and outbound servers.  Note that for "Normal KPassword" to work you will need to log into your gmail account from a web browser and enable “Allow less secure apps”

[here](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps) is the link to the google account setting. 
[Google tool screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sxsm2.png)

Alternately you can wait/force the install of the latest Thunderbird release in the beta class for the OAuth fix.

Answer (score 0):

I went to `Account Settings > Account > Authentication Method` and changed it from Normal Password to `Oauth2`

Answer (score 0):

"allow less secure apps" is no longer available. when I'm back on pc tbird I'll try the old password change.

Comment: As of now, password login method to Gmail is not supported anymore. OAuth2 must be used, or an application password (but application password can be created only when you have 2FA enabled on your account). Google has informed since long about this change.